# Pandas DataFrame: Calculate difference (which is no. of days) for each row, satisfying a condition dynamically

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-analysis

**Consider the below DataSet Screenshot:**

[image]

```
pd.DataFrame({'Date': ['05/10/2018','08/10/2018','09/10/2018','10/10/2018','11/10/2018','12/10/2018','15/10/2018','16/10/2018','17/10/2018','19/10/2018','22/10/2018','23/10/2018','24/10/2018','25/10/2018','26/10/2018','29/10/2018','30/10/2018','31/10/2018'],
              'Open': [271,259.75,268,261.6,268,266,264.4,264.6,273.75,259.7,266,258,260.25,254.5,252,250,267.5,275],
              'High': [271,268.5,268.15,280.45,271.5,267.9,265.7,270.85,275,264.2,266,259,261.8,255,252.5,269.25,279.1,282.75],
              'Low': [256,258.35,260,261.2,260.6,261.5,261.1,263.35,260,258.1,259.45,255,252.8,248.4,247.4,248.4,266,268.6],
              'Close': [258.35,265.75,262.95,278.65,262.15,263.75,263.2,270.3,261.15,261.1,260.35,255.65,255.7,249.55,248.1,267.9,273.15,281.4]})
```

I want to calculate the difference between dates for each row where current row 'High' is broken. Let's say, for example, for 30/10/18 'High' is 279.1. Now, I want to find the Date (backwards) where this 'High' is broken (the first Date/index where it is broken). In this case, it is 10/10/2018 ('High' is 280.45). So, there is no such specific period (which I can mention for comparison). This is dynamic.

Now, In my DataFrame, I need to add a Column which will show the difference between such dates (Here, it is 12).

My approach to above problem is by slicing the DataFrame containing the new row, each time and then see where the 'High' is broken, thus calculating the difference between them. Something like this,

```
for index in range(df.shape[0]):
     av_data = df[:index+1]

for index in range(-2, -av_data.shape[0], -1):
     if av_data['High'].iloc[index] > av_data['High'].iloc[-1]:
         #Our Logic to find the no. of days
         break`
```

Although, it is working but I think there is a major drawback in terms of performance coz this need to be applied on whole Dataset (which could be more than 2000 rows) and moreover, I am not familiar with the in-built functions Pandas that can achieve the same thing.

Comment: Giving a "DataSet Screenshot" is rather impractical. If now somebody wants to solve your problem for you they would have to come up with their own example to work on. Try to include example data that is copyable.

Comment: @user2640045 Sorry for that. I have uploaded the DataSet.